# Design patterns

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, model-view-controller, design-patterns

Someone said to me once that rendering a controller action inside a view is a bad design decision. Can you guys recommend some resource where i can get more information, advice and examples on what is a good/bad design and why. This way i can learn how to take better design decision and recognize where future problem may occurs.

Comment: learn about OO design - good place to start is Head First Object-Oriented Analysis and Design published by O'Reilly Media

Answer (score 1):

Rendering controller actions in a view is not bad design, it just doesn't make sense. You don't render controller actions you render views. render = draw. How would you draw an action?

You render views either directly within a view or from a controller action. Both are extremely common and totally acceptable practices.

Perhaps if you explained what you are thinking then you might get an answer but for the minuite all I can say is

In your view links and buttons got to controller actions and render statements render view template partials which is pretty much all you'll ever want to do.

**Update**

It just occured to me that you might be referring to view syntax similar to this

```
<%= render :action => "action2" %>
```

This is very misleading as it leads you to think you are making a call action2 when you are not. you are rendering the action2 template. It's kinda the only way you can get a template rendered instead of a partial which is mostly totally unnecessary mainly because you would really only want to use part of a full template.

if action2 rendered a template called action_2_template.html.erb and there was no action_2.html.erb template then the above code would give you an error of template not found even though you have an action2 action

Answer (score 1):

A very good resource to seek good RoR practice is the book

**Rails AntiPatterns: Best Practice Ruby on Rails Refactoring** by Chad Pytel and Tammer Saleh

This book definitely helped me a lot in improving my Rails programming practices.

Answer (score 0):

[RubyOnRails.org](http://rubyonrails.org/) provides an extensive source of documentation and tutorials for proper use of code conventions/standards.

Answer (score 0):

(I am going to assume you mean design in a general sense, not rails specific. I am also going to assume you are a professional dev trying to up his skills. If either of those are not the case, this answer doesn't really apply)

Code design is a massive topic, and (unfortunately) most of the good books are written with java in mind. I would start with "Head First Design Patterns" for a great intro to the subject, move on to "Clean Code" (should be mandatory reading for all professional developers IMO) for heuristics and techniques in day to day development, Domain Driven Design for great guidelines on building large systems, and finally Patterns of Enterprise Application Architecture to give a great foundation of common patterns found in successfully designed large systems.